# Any way to force the Windows Task Bar to hide (if in "auto hide" mode)

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I have my Win 7 taskbar set to autohide but its often pops up... and just stays visible, obscuring the bottom of all other programs (since they are behaving correctly (as if the Task Bar isn't there b/c it's supposed to autohide).

Any way to force it to HIDE again?

Comment: http://rocketdock.com/addon/misc/3425

Answer (score 9):

Adding to what [DougMelvin posted](https://superuser.com/a/321221/111643), here's a script that I found a while back...

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe 
start explorer.exe
```

Upon saving the batch file, I created a shortcut to the desktop and added shortcut key.

Ex.  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

This forced the task bar to auto hide when explorer restarted.

Comment: Well, that hides the taskbar, I guess. But then it never comes back and I have to restart Windows.

Answer (score 6):

The Auto-Hiding of the "*Task-Bar*" can be forced by Two Subsequent Left-Clicks on the "*Start*" Button.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand what you're trying to convey.

Comment: Strange, @gronostaj. We have been as explicit as we could. It is quite simple: the auto-hiding of the "_Task-Bar_" can be forced by Two Subsequent Left-Clicks on the "_Start_" Button. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Now I get it. You could replace your entire answer with just this one sentence and I would consider it a significant improvement. People who come here want to get their problem solved. A clear, concise sentence is better than two screens of unhelpful text with screenshots and an unrelated Mick Jagger story. I appreciate your effort, but it's counter-productive.

Comment: Did that, @gronostaj.

Answer (score 5):

This happens to me when a programs want's to give me a notification and windows is set to not show the notification.

The program in question just can't deal with it and keeps trying and the silly taskbar won't go away.

The only solution I have found short of reloggin/rebooting is to open the task manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>) then find and kill explorer.exe.

Then in the run menu of task manager type "explorer".

Your desktop comes back, all taskbar and notification area icons accounted for (unlike in previous version of windows) and more importantly, your taskbar will now autohide.

No running programs should be harmed.

Answer (score 2):

Clicking twice on the Start button (or pressing the Windows key on your keyboard twice) is the quick, practical solution.  There doesn't seem to be any way to prevent the non-hiding to happen on a permanent basis.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Is it because I'm using Windows 11?

Answer (score 1):

It won't hide again if you move your mouse over it and then away?  I think it should once you restore focus to something else.

Some programs steal focus, which may be causing the issue.  One that I have encountered a lot is logitech mouse mapping software - once you launch it, it runs in the background but may randomly steal focus.

Next time it happens, click on one of your open windows and see if the taskbar goes away again.

Are you using any mouse or keymapping programs?

Answer (score 0):

Ime this happens when a program has some sort of "notification" or alert (sometimes these are not obvious).  Typically the app icon on the taskbar will be lit or highlighted in some way.  If that's the case for you just click the app icon (bring the prog window forward/into focus) and the task bar will hide normally after that.

Answer (score 0):

This will not eliminate the root cause, but it will hide the task bar.

1. Click on the "search button" in the task bar. The search dialog box will open.
2. Click on an empty area of your desktop.

The task bar will hide.

Answer (score -2):

See this, attached file at bottom of first post, instructions on another page.

http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/44913-disabletaskbarontop-disable-taskbar-always-top.html