# Finding which process has taken the taskbar captive

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

The 'refusing to auto-hide' taskbar on Windows has frustrated me for years and despite trying lots of hacks, only restarting the explorer process reliably works without fail when I can't locate which app is begging to be acknowledged.

I suspect there is one process regularly doing is. Is there anyway other than uninstalling app by app to track him down?

**Update**: By 'refusing to auto-hide', I refer to the issue when the taskbar automatically pops up and refuses to go down. Often this is due to a notification in the system tray which requires acknowledgement before the taskbar will go down. If one is lucky, the system tray will highlight the annoying app, other times not.

Comment: What's the "... 'refusing to auto-hide' taskbar on Windows"

Comment: As mentioned in http://superuser.com/questions/169899/any-way-to-force-the-windows-task-bar-to-hide-if-in-auto-hide-mode. Sorry, due to the thousands of times it's happened to me across multiple Windows OSs, I just thought it was a well known design issue.

Comment: there is a program called "Taskbar Slapper" in existance on the web, I have not tried it yet, because like you I learned it has to do with notifications. I solved some of it by adjusting notifications, and removing or adjusting things that toss them up. (presentaly unsolved really)

Comment: Tried Taskbar Slapper many years ago but didn't have much success with it (plus not too fond of the bandaids, I'd rather find the perpetrator).